# How can I get ten numbers and displays the biggest and lowest one?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, date-comparison

sorry I'm a newbie and I'm trying to write a program to get ten integers from user with a an Inputbox or Textbox and displays the biggest and lowest one in a label with visual basic. I'll be appreciated if you help me out with this. 
Thank you. this is my solution. I don't know how to compare these ten numbers with each other.

```
Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
        Dim i, Container, Max, Numbers
        Max = 0
        i = 1


        While (i <= 10)
            Numbers = InputBox("please enter a number", "Enter a number")
            Max = Numbers
            Container = Container & " " & Numbers
            i = i + 1
        End While
        lblresult.Text = Container
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

conceptually speaking you should use a List(Of Integer) or List(Of Double), perform the loop 10 times adding the value into the list.

Suppose this is our list

```
Dim container As New List(Of Integer)
```

To get input

```
Dim userInput = ""
Dim input As Integer

userInput = InputBox("please enter a number", "Enter a number")
If Integer.TryParse(userInput, input) Then
    container.Add(input)
End If
```

After the loop

```
Console.WriteLine($"Min: {container.Min()} Max: {container.Max()}")
```

Does this make sense to you ?

**Edit**, based on asking for Windows Forms example.

You could do the following instead of a InputBox, requires a label, a button and a TextBox.

[image]

```
Public Class MainForm
    Private container As New List(Of Integer)

    Private Sub CurrentInputTextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) _
        Handles CurrentInputTextBox.KeyPress

        If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        CurrentLabel.Text = "Enter number 1"
    End Sub
    Private Sub ContinueButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles ContinueButton.Click

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CurrentInputTextBox.Text) Then

            container.Add(CInt(CurrentInputTextBox.Text))
            CurrentLabel.Text = $"Enter number {container.Count + 1}"

            If container.Count = 10 Then
                ContinueButton.Enabled = False
                CurrentLabel.Text =
                    $"Count: {container.Count} " &
                    $"Max: {container.Max()} " &
                    $"Min: {container.Min()}"
            Else
                ActiveControl = CurrentInputTextBox
                CurrentInputTextBox.Text = ""
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It's a personal choice, personally don't care for InputBox. I would never use one myself and never have as there is no control over user input while a better choice IMHO is to use a TextBox using an event to guard from non numerics (and optionally set the property ShortcutEnabled to false for no paste from the windows clipboard) as presented or even better a custom TextBox which only accepts numerics yet that would be overkill for this exercise. @Immortality can use an InputBox it if they like, nothing stopping this.

Comment: I agree about the `InputBox` but  this seems like a beginner question and rolling your own input box is probably a bit advanced. I don't like .KeyPress. I think it is very annoying for the user. Argh! My keyboard is not working! How about the validating event with the ErrProvider?

Comment: Sure ErrorProvider and validating event is a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't want to do your homework for you but I was afraid you might be hopelesly confused.

First let's go over **your code**. See comments

```
Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
    Dim i, Container, Max, Numbers 'Don't declare variables without an As clause
    Max = 0 'Max is an object
    i = 1 'i is and object
    While i <= 10 'the parenthesis are unnecessary. You can't use <= 2 with an object
        Numbers = InputBox("please enter a number", "Enter a number")
        Max = Numbers
        Container = Container & " " & Numbers 'Container is an object; you can't use & with an object
        i = i + 1 'Again with the object i can't use +
    End While
    lblresult.Text = Container
End Sub
```

Now **my approach**.

I created a `List(Of T)` at the `Form` level so it can be seen from different procedures. The `T` stands for type. I could be a built in type or type you create by creating a `Class`.

The first click event fills the list with the inputted numbers. I used `.TryParse` to test if the input is a correct value. The first parameter is a string; the input from the user. The second parameter is a variable to hold the converted string. `.TryParse` is very clever. It returns `True` or `False` base on whether the input string can be converted to the correct type and it fills the second parameter with the converted value.

The second click event loops through the list building a string to display in `Label1`. Then we use methods available to `List(Of T)` to get the numbers you desire.

```
Private NumbersList As New List(Of Integer)

Private Sub FillNumberList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    While i < 10
        Dim input = InputBox("Please enter a whole number")
        Dim inputInt As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(input, inputInt) Then
            NumbersList.Add(inputInt)
            i += 1 'We only increment i if the parse is succesful
        End If
    End While
    MessageBox.Show("Finished Input")
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayResults_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Label1.Text = "You input these numbers "
    For Each num In NumbersList
        Label1.Text &= $"{num}, "
    Next
    Label2.Text = $"The largest number is {NumbersList.Max}"
    Label3.Text = $"The smallest number is {NumbersList.Min}"
End Sub
```